# What's the standards-compliant code for deploying a Java applet in an HTML5 document?

Tags: java, html

I would like to deploy an old Java (1.5) applet in an HTML5 web page.

Most of the material available on the web regarding Java applets and HTML5 is either outdated, does not work, or contains myriad hacks and workarounds for cross-browser compatibility. I have the luxury of not having to care about compatibility, though.

I realise that the HTML5 standard is still under development, but much of it is stable enough for people to use. So browser hacks aside, what's the (likely-to-be-)standards-compliant method for embedding a Java applet in a `jar` file, and what is its approximate browser support?

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 is still under development. About the applets says in the Draft:

> Generally speaking, it is better to avoid using applets like these and
>   instead use native JavaScript and HTML to provide the functionality,
>   since that way the application will work on all Web browsers without
>   requiring a third-party plugin. Many devices, especially embedded
>   devices, do not support third-party technologies like Java.

However, the review indicates that to embed an applet can use the following *idiom*:

```
<figure>
  <object type="application/x-java-applet">
    <param name="code" value="MyJavaClass">
    <p>You do not have Java available, or it is disabled.</p>
  </object>
  <figcaption>My Java Clock</figcaption>
</figure>
```

HTML5 encourages the use of the `<object>` tag, that can be used to embed media in your website.

Comment: It's the details I need elaboration on — where does the URL for the `jar` file go? Do I need to specify the class to be loaded? Do I need some other magic parameters (like the `classid` of HTML4)?

Comment: You can see an example running in http://teachmeprogramming.com/media/html5applet.html. For more details about the object tag, see in http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/single-page.html#the-object-element

Comment: @PaulVargas - Unfortunately the information at the two links you provide contradict one another, with the first using a bunch of attributes that don't exist on `<object>` according to the second.

Comment: Yes! That's the problem. Then we need use JavaScript for ask for the browser and the version for to do it _cross-browser_. :-(